# Recoverable fatal error after form submission in drupal7

Tags: 7

Iam new to drupal.I have created a custom module named firstmodule .I have created a form using the tutorials section of drupal 7
when is submit i want to store this details in the registration which is present in db.

firstmodule.module

```
function firstmodule_form1_submit($form, &$form_state)

{

$firstname = $form_state['values']['name'];
    $username = $form_state['values']['username'];
    $password = $form_state['values']['password'];
    $year_of_birth = $form_state['values']['year_of_birth'];
    $email = $form_state['values']['email'];
    $file = $form_state['values']['file'];
```

I am using the insert query in the following way:

```
        db_insert('registration')->fields(array(
          'firstname' => $firstname,
          'username' => $username,
          'password' => $password,
          'yearofbirth' =>$year_of_birth,
          'email' => $email,
          'file' => $file,))
          ->execute();
}
```

it is showing me the error

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be
>   converted to string in DatabaseStatementBase->execute() (line 2168 of
>   /var/www/drupal-7.22/includes/database/database.inc).

please help with it

Comment: there is not enough information to help you, are you trying to upload files?

Comment: ya my uploading is done and my files are even moving to a folder files in drupal.the problem is after successful validation and clicking on submit button iam not able to store the values in the database.it throws the above error.

Comment: I have solved my issue everything is saving in database but the uploaded file path is not saving i used $form_state['values']['file'] to store path in db but not storing

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of a file upload with some validation, hope it helps

```
function file_upload_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {

  $file = file_save_upload('file', array(
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('txt csv'), 
    'file_validate_size' => array(10000000),
  ));
  // If the file passed validation:
  if ($file) {
    // Move the file, into the Drupal file system
    if ($file = file_move($file, 'public://')) {
      // Save the file for use in the submit handler.
      $form_state['storage']['file'] = $file;
    }
    else {
      form_set_error('file', 'there was an error uploading the file');
    }
  }
  else {
    form_set_error('file', 'No file uploaded');
  }
}

function file_upload_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $file = $form_state['storage']['file'];
  // We are done with the file, remove it from storage.
  unset($form_state['storage']['file']);
  // Make the storage of the file permanent
  $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
  // Save file status.
  file_save($file);
  // here you can save your data
  $firstname = $form_state['values']['name'];
  $username = $form_state['values']['username'];
  $password = $form_state['values']['password'];
  $year_of_birth = $form_state['values']['year_of_birth'];
  $email = $form_state['values']['email'];

  db_insert('registration')->fields(array(
    'firstname' => $firstname,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'yearofbirth' =>$year_of_birth,
    'email' => $email,
    'file' => $file->uri,))
  ->execute();

}
```

Comment: thanks it worked but it is saving public://practice_0.jpeg in database is it right

Comment: yep, drupal manages files with stream wrappers, a very useful feature

Comment: Thankyou so much Cornelius.This is my first task in drupal creating a registration form.You really helped a lot.now i will start with creating login form and make the user to login.if you can give me the suggestion for login iam so glad.Thankyou once again for helping

Comment: You are welcome, Drupal has this functionality out of the box, i suggest you to read more about user management in the docs.

Comment: ok Thankyou for your suggestion i will go through it